# Using regex to replace a variable amount of groups within only part of a string

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to use regular expressions to do quick fixes to HTML tables.  I'm rather new to regex, so I've been stumped with this problem for a couple hours now:

The input string will be a table, with a variable amount of rows and columns:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        ...
    </thead>
    ...
</table>
```

I would like to use regular expressions to change all `<td>` and `</td>` tags into `<th>` and `</th>` tags within only the header.  I've found its easy enough to change *all* `<td>` tags to `<th>`, but there will obviously be tags I do not want to change.

Is there a way to do this in one pass?

Ideally, this would work through the Visual Studio find-and-replace function.

I apologize if this has been asked  already--I don't yet know enough terminology with regex to search for it properly.

Comment: Search for `(<\/?)td>(?=(?:(?!<thead>)[\s\S])*<\/thead>)` and replace with `$1th>`

Comment: Do you have any pattern that you can use to determine which `<td>` you want to replace from the ones you don't? If not, you'll need to do the selection manually.

Comment: @revo This didn't seem to work.  Maybe I've done something wrong...  I'll try again in a bit

Comment: @Barmar The only pattern is that they appear before </thead>

Comment: Try with `(<\/?)td>(?=(?:(?!<thead>)[\n\r\s\S])*<\/thead>)` I think there's something wrong with VSC.

Comment: @revo This worked!  I assume then that there isn't a way to do this within a single replacement?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + ENTER replaces all in VSC.